# How to handle google api oauth in this app?

Tags: python, google-oauth

My client asked me to build a tool that would let him and his partners to upload video to youtube to his channel automatically .

For example let's say that my client is A and he has some buisness partners . A want to be able to upload videos to his channel, that is easy to do, but the problem here is to let other parners B and C to upload their videos to His channel (channel of the person of A) .

In this case I would need "A" to auth my app so he can upload videos to his own channel, but how can I handle that for other users . How can users use the access token of the person "A" to upload videos to his channel ?

**What I've done so far ?**

I've got the youtube upload python sample from google api docs and played with it a bit. I tried to `subprocess.Popen(cmd)` where **cmd** is the following command : `python upload.py --file "video name"  --title "title of the vid"` . 
This will lead the user to auth my app once , that's only fine for the "A" person .The others won't be able to do that, since they need to upload the vid to A's account .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a server-side script in which you use Google OAuth to upload videos to A's account.

Then you can create a client-side app which allows your clients B and C to upload their videos to the server; on completion, the server can then upload them to A's account.

Alternatively, to avoid uploading twice, if you trust the clients and would like them to be able to upload directly, you can pass them an OAuth access token to A's account.